# UpdateData AMPScript doesn't work on MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, mobileconnect

I am using the below AMPScript in my TextReponse SMS

```
%%[ var @response 
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUN(0)]  
Output(v(@response)) 
UpdateData("InnovationDE", 1, "subscriberkey", "ContactID_24", "last", "kammes") ]%%
```

I get the error

> "There was error processing your message"

As soon as I remove the UpdateData, it works. 
Have also tried **UpsertData** but same issue.
Also tried 
**UpdateData("InnovationDE", 1, "phone", MOBILE_NUMBER, "last", "kammes")** but same issue.

My DE (InnovationDE) is a simple one. Just has 4 columns (SubscriberKey, First, Last, email, phone) 
Seems like I am missing something fundamental here.
Please help

Comment: have you tried using `INSERTDATA` ?

Comment: I need to update only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but there are some caveats:

1. Ensure SubscriberKey is the primary key in your DE
2. <s>I don't believe you can access the [MSG(0).VERB(0)] & [MSG(0).NOUN(0)] values in a TextResponse type message. Those will need to be omitted or you need a different message type.</s>
3. Ensure there is **always** a response value returned **or** check Suppress Response Message option and never output anything.
4. Move your output function oustide of the main script block. Try the code below and see if it works for you.

   `%%[
   var @response
   set @response = UpdateData("InnovationDE", 1, "subscriberkey", "ContactID_24", "last", "kammes")
   ]%%%%=v(@response)=%%`

Comment: Thank you so much Jim. [MSG(0).VERB(0)] & [MSG(0).NOUN(0)] definitely works in a TextResponse. Here is what finally worked for me -       `%%[ var @response set @response = [MSG(0).NOUN(0)]   ]%%%%[ Output(v(@response)) ]%%  %%[ var@update set @update = UpsertData("InnovationDE", 1, "phone", MOBILE_NUMBER, "first", @response) ]%%%%[@update]%%`

Comment: Good to hear - thanks for following up. I'm not sure why I am unable to use the verb & noun properties in my TextResponse but perhaps that related to a different issue.